# Why is my JSONP response blank/error from SOLR at localhost?

Tags: jquery, solr, jsonp

I've set up Solr locally. It works fine using queries in browser. I'm tryng to acces JSON-queryresults in JQuery, but I'm not able.

When I run the following request in my browser i get the following resut:
http://localhost:8983/solr/Products/select?q=HPI-850&fl=id%2CPris&&rows=2&wt=json&json.wrf=solrCallback

```
solrCallback({
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"HPI-850",
      "json.wrf":"solrCallback",
      "fl":"id,Pris",
      "rows":"2",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3701,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "Pris":1195,
        "id":"10440"},
      {
        "Pris":1195,
        "id":"16656"}]
  }})
```

Running the following code in my browser at localhost I get the JSONP response from the example I found at https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/, but I get no response from my own URL. Why? I my code bad, or does Solr block the request in any way?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>FRA TEST</h1>
    <div id="Test_JSON"></div>
    <br /><br />
    <h1>FRA SOLR</h1>
    <div id="SOLR_JSON"></div>
    <script>
        function jsonCallback(json) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(json));
            $("#Test_JSON").html(JSON.stringify(json));
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-2.json",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });


        function solrCallback(json) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(json));
            $("#SOLR_JSON").html(JSON.stringify(json));
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/Products/select?q=HPI-850&wt=json&json.wrf=solrCallback",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your browser's debug console show? What does the network panel for the request show? Is the response identical to what you see in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the details of why it did not work with JSONP, because as I understand, it should have worked. While searching for a solution I ended up enabling CORS in Solr.

I followed this guide:
http://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-solr/

After doing so, I have no problem getting my Json from Solr by JQuery.